# Drawing contours retrieved from the binary image

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, drawing, contour

I want use `findContours` with the binary image, but the callback function causes an error:

> Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap

when returning.

When i want to use `clear()` to free the `vector<vector<Point> >` value, it causes the same exception and the code crashed in free.c at the line:

```
if (retval == 0) errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
```

For example:

```
void onChangeContourMode(int, void *)
{
    Mat m_frB = imread("3.jpg", 0);
    vector<vector<Point>> contours
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(m_frB, contours, hierarchy, g_contour_mode, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for( int idx = 0 ; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
    drawContours( m_frB, contours, idx, Scalar(255,255,255), 
    CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
    imshow( "Contours", m_frB );
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mat m_frB = imread("3.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

loads `3.jpg` as a 8bpp grayscale image, so it's not binary image. It is specific for [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) function that *"non-zero pixels are treated as 1’s. Zero pixels remain 0’s, so the image is treated as binary"*. Also note that this *"function modifies the image while extracting the contours"*.

The actual problem here is that although the destination image is 8bpp, you should make sure that it has 3 channels by using `CV_8UC3` before you draw RGB contours into it. Try this:

```
// find contours:
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(m_frB, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// draw contours:
Mat imgWithContours = Mat::zeros(m_frB.rows, m_frB.cols, CV_8UC3);
RNG rng(12345);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(50, 255), rng.uniform(50,255), rng.uniform(50,255));
    drawContours(imgWithContours, contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy, 0);
}
imshow("Contours", imgWithContours);
```

Comment: Yes,you are right!I didn't notice the usage of drawContours().Thx!